# NPE in android layout

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I developed some android program, but it throws NLE on android 4.4.2 and works well on android 4.1.2.

I think the problem is : setContentView(R.layout.drawerlayout);
but my drawerlayout is OK with no errors.

partly code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setContentView(R.layout.drawerlayout);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

  SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("setting", 0); // 0 - for private mode


      login=pref.getBoolean("loged_in", false);


    Drawable d=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.action_bar_bg);  
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(d);


    try {
        catnum = 1;
        addcat("دسته بندی ها",0);
        new CateFetch().execute("a","c", "b");
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mPlanetTitles = arr;// getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    } catch (Exception E) {
    }


    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
            ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
    }
}
```

logcat:

```
07-26 09:14:07.519    2167-2167/com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 91K, 6% free 2900K/3068K, paused 33ms, total 36ms
07-26 09:14:07.859    2167-2167/com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
07-26 09:14:07.859    2167-2167/com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2aa3ba8)
07-26 09:14:07.919    2167-2167/com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 28K, 3% free 3383K/3488K, paused 22ms, total 23ms
07-26 09:14:07.929    2167-2167/com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample, PID: 2167
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2091)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:672)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

how to resolve?

Comment: Is the line `mPlanetTitles = arr;// getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);` and thus `mPlanetTitles` initialized?

Comment: it definded int the class: private String[] mPlanetTitles;

Comment: no, I mean does the `arr` have a value from anywhere.

Comment: yes have public static String [] arr=new String[10];

Comment: Is there any reason, why you use `0` instead of `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`???? Also: do you initialize the elements of `arr` or do they remain `null`?

Comment: Does `arr` contain any values after that or is it full of nulls?

Comment: arr will be filled in an AsyncTask.

Comment: no reason for use 0 instead of Context.MODE_PRIVATE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not related to `setContentView(R.layout.drawerlayout);`

arr must have elements before `mPlanetTitles = arr;// getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);`

add a `arr= new String[]{"some string"};`early in **onCreate**

or change where your **Array** is filled.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that all elements in the `ArrayAdapter` are non-`null` when the `ListView` tries to add it's child views. Otherwise that causes a NPE. Using an `AsyncTask` to fill the elements won't work without some changes, since it doesn't guaranty to fill the array before the `ListView` adds it's children.

If you want to fill the `ArrayAdapter` from an `AsyncTask`, either create the `ArrayAdapter` with a `List` (I'd suggest `ArrayList`) as constructor argument, replacing the array or remove the array as parameter to make the `ArrayAdapter` create it's own list. Use [`ArrayAdapter.add(T)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#add%28T%29) from a method of the `AsyncTask`, that runs on the UI thread, e.g. [`onProgressUpdate(Progress...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29), to fill the `ArrayAdapter`.